# Factorization in Anticommutative Rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

[Prof. Valdes and Prof. Anderson](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371955_Factorization_in_Commutative_Rings_with_Zero_Divisors) studied factorization in commutative rings with zero divisors. I was wondering how similar factorization is in anticommutative rings with zero divisiors.

Comment: Do you have a link to the article of Valdes & Anderson? Also do you really mean anti-commutative ($ab = -ab$) or 'just' non-commutative?

Comment: @Vincent I mean anticommutative. An example of anticommutative ring is R^3 under the cross product.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38371955_Factorization_in_Commutative_Rings_with_Zero_Divisors

Comment: Okay. So they are naturally riddled with zero divisors as $x^2 = 0$ for all $x$ in such a ring. The most prominent examples are probably Lie algebras and exterior algebras $\bigwedge V$ for some vector space $V$. I would expect people have looked at factorization in those examples at least, but I don't know a reference

Comment: @Vincent Lie algebras aren't associative, so it's not clear what factorization would mean in that context (but maybe that's a good notion) and $\bigwedge V$ is not anticommutative in this strong sense because even wedges commute.

Comment: @Insulin69 To my knowledge, very little has been done so far towards the study of factorization in (non-associative) magmas and, more in particular, in non-associative rings (though much depends on what you mean by the "study of factorization"). There is, however, a lot that could be done.

Comment: @WillSawin ah good points. But then what are examples? Exterior algebras where the even degrees are artificially set to zero?

Comment: @Vincent I guess the $\mathbb R^3$ example isn't associative, so maybe actually associativity isn't a problem for this, and Lie algebras form a natural set of examples.

Comment: Well it looks like I found another research topic! I don't think I have the right kind of mind myself though to figure this out.